# How to extract data from message using serial port in C#

Tags: c#, tcp, serial-port

I have a project that  read  message from serial port adn respond some messages .I have this message:

```
"+CMGL: 3,\"REC READ\",\"+905444444411\",\"\",\"15/03/17,11:17:11+08\"\r\n#2220 #*5491111111*\r\n\r\nOK\r\n"
```

I want to exctract +905444444411 and 5491111111 and 2220 from this message .
How can I do this.

Comment: you should use regex for this

Comment: Google regex.  The C# class is System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.

Comment: may you gime me an example..

Comment: Could write you an example, but it would just be repeating the thousands, if not millions, you could find with a couple of google searches.

Comment: One more hint, I like using [regexpal](http://regexpal.com) when I need to create a new expression like this.

Comment: Probably simpler than regex: read lines, `Split()` at the commas. Gives you more control over the parsing process and eventually better error messages

Comment: @DrKoch, Split() might help. But a couple of the fields aren't cleanly delineated by commas.  I'm still thinking regex would be useful.  Maybe not absolutely necessary, but wouldn't hurt to learn :)